# Como mudar a versão do PHP em que o Composer é executado no Linux?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, composer

Eu instalei o composer no meu Ubuntu através do seguinte comando:

```
apt-get install composer
```

O Ubuntu atualmente suporta múltiplas versões de PHP instaladas. Eu tenho o PHP5.6, PHP7.0 e PHP7.1 instalados na minha máquina.

Quando eu tinha apenas o PHP5.6, o comando `php` rodava essa versão, então eu não tinha problemas com o Composer.

Porém ao instalar as versões `7.*`, o Composer passou a ser executado com a versão `7.1` do PHP instalado.

Como eu faço para o Composer instalado globalmente rode com outra versão do PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No meu caso, eu resolvi da seguinte forma.

Ao dar um `which php`, o mesmo aponta para o caminho `/usr/bin/php`. Descobri que na verdade isso é apenas um link para a instalação mais recente do php.

Então eu deletei o `link` e criei outro apontando para a versão 5.6 do PHP.

Assim:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/php
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/bin/php
```

Se você executar o comando `php -v`, vai notar que o resultado será algo parecido com isso:

```
php -v

> PHP 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli)
```

Assim, ao rodar o `composer install`, o PHP executado será a versão colocada no link simbólico de `/usr/bin/php`.

## Atualização

A maneira utilizada acima foi uma maneira manual que eu utilizei para resolver o problema, porém a forma mais recomendável é usar o comando do próprio Linux, chamado `update-alternatives`. Com ele podemos determinar links simbólicos para determinados comandos.

Basta fazer assim:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Se desejar usar a versão `7.1`, por exemplo, basta fazer:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

Lembrando que as versões do PHP deverão estar instaladas no seu SO :p

Comment: muito bom, eu mantenho 2 versões do PHP e o HHVM mais ou menos desta forma que citou +1