# Composer erro 'Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado'

Tags: php, composer

instalei o composer seguindo as [instruções do site](https://getcomposer.org/download/), passando o diretório `/usr/local/bin` e nome do arquivo `composer`. Mas, quando executo:

`$ composer install`

ou outro comando do composer retorna o erro:

`/usr/bin/env: php: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado`

Comment: Possivelmente você não possui um link para o PHP em `usr/bin/env`, então pode tentar `php composer install`.

Comment: Tentei com o `php` antes mas também deu erro.

Comment: Você tem o PHP instalado?

Comment: Sim, acho que encontrei o problema, tentei instalar outra versão do php e agora tenho que digitar `php5` na linha de comando para reconhecer o php. Encontrei uma solução aqui [Como mudar a versão do PHP em que o Composer é executado no Linux?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190556/como-mudar-a-vers%C3%A3o-do-php-em-que-o-composer-%C3%A9-executado-no-linux) valeu pela atenção